# ListView inside CardView remove top margin on scroll down

Tags: android, listview

In this example, I have a `ListView` embedded into a `CardView`. For visual purposes, there is an 8dp margin on top of this `CardView`. The desired behaviour is that as the user starts to scroll down, this top margin should disappear. Until now I could achieve this only by embedding the `CardView` inside a `ScrollView`, and as the list tends to be big, this was ruining the performance greatly. Any suggestions how to fix this?

```xml
<LinearLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:style="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"     
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    android:background="@color/background"    
    android:paddingTop="8dp"     
    android:paddingStart="4dp"   
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"   
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"    
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> 

        <RelativeLayout
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" 
             android:background="@color/sample_white"  
             android:orientation="vertical">     

          <ListView            
               android:id="@+id/list"     
               android:layout_width="match_parent"  
               android:layout_height="match_parent" />  
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

I will try to make things clearer with an image that shows the margin in question.

[image: ListView embedded in CardView top margin]

Now when I am scrolling down, the list elements move up but the margin is still there and makes the list look strange.

Comment: in your CardView add this property `card_view:useCompatPadding=true`

Comment: @Ironman thank you for your reply, however that didn't help. Please take a look at the attached image, I hope the problem is this way clearer.